# How can i stop slideToggle closing unless first drop down is selected

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm relatively new to jQuery and need some help to fix an issue i have.
I wrote this script to show a quantity box when someone selects an option from a drop down select list. The client requested a "Reset Selection" link next to the drop down which i have.
The problem is that if someone makes a selection, but then changes their mind and choses a different option, the slideToggle is triggered again which then hides the quantity box and add to cart button.
Is there any way to make this function so that it will only slideToggle closed if the first "select option" choice is clicked, or the "reset" link, as opposed to any other option.

Hope that makes sense.

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
<!--
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".expcontent").hide();
jQuery(".reset").hide();        
jQuery(".back").change(function(){
jQuery(".expcontent").slideToggle(800);
jQuery(".reset").show();
});
jQuery(".reset").click(function(){ 
jQuery(".reset").hide();
jQuery(".expcontent").slideToggle(800);
jQuery('.back option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
});
});
</script>
```

Based on the responses given below, i have tried:

```
jQuery(".back").change(function(){
var sel=jQuery('.back option:first')
if (sel) 
jQuery(".expcontent").slideUp(800);
else 
jQuery(".expcontent").slideDown(800);
```

but slideDown never occurs using this so i'm assuming the condition for var sel isn't being met. Is it even a valid condition? I'm struggling to find much info on how to tell if the first option in a "select" drop down has been chosen.

Worked it out. replaced

```
var sel=jQuery(".back option:first")
```

with

```
var sel=jQuery(".back option:first").attr('selected')
```

Comment: You can check if the selected option is the first one, then you can do a `slideDown()` or `slideUp()` instead of using `slideToggle`.

Comment: @deadlock Can you point me in the right direction for checking which option is selected. Sorry, not been doing this very long. Thanks for the info on slideDown and slideUp though.

Comment: The guy below just written the way in his answer. I still recommend that you search and learn by yourself. Then you can ask here when you face a problem.

Comment: @deadlock I agree. I just ordered a couple of books off Amazon i'm waiting on so i can learn more about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sel=$('#.back option:selected');

if(sel)
$(".expcontent").slideDown(800);

else 
$(".expcontent").slideUp(800);
```

Comment: Although slideUp() and slideDown is the right option here, the solution provided won't actually work as there is always an option selected, even if it is the first one in the drop down list i.e. Please select an option. It will fail to slideUp using that solution. I will try and find a solution that will allow it to slideUp if only the first option is selected.

Comment: Yes, i just need to work out how to check which option is selected.

Comment: using var sel=jQuery(".back option:first").attr('selected')i got it to work.